# Android | usage of the UPDATE_PACKAGES permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to update a package that is pre-loaded inside the image using Android's `PackageInstaller` as mentioned below.

The corresponding app is a privileged app and is installed inside `/system/priv-app`. So ideally, I think having the `android.permission.UPDATE_PACKAGES` will enough to carry a package update. The same permission is mentioned under `/etc/permissions/privapp-permissions-atv.xml` for this app.

But for some reason, it fails and gives the below error at the `BroadcastReceiver` that I have implemented.

```
android.content.pm.extra.STATUS : -1
android.content.pm.extra.SESSION_ID : 344244195
android.intent.extra.INTENT : Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.CONFIRM_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.google.android.packageinstaller (has extras) }
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to add the `INSTALL_PACKAGES` as well or is there a feature or any other configuration at the device side needs to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's no such permission as `UPDATE_PACKAGES`. But in the Android security best practices have clearly mentioned this permission - https://source.android.com/security/best-practices/app

[image]

However, the correct permission is `INSTALL_PACKAGE_UPDATES` and it has the capability to update the packages which are already installed in the system.

This is totally unexpected and misleading information from Google/Android and I had to spend weeks to find out the reason for this particular issue. Not sure why this has not been addressed yet!